# Creepy movment with IK

Tags: armature, bones

What is it that create this creepy effect [image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Seeing as we don't know what the model is meant to do, we can't tell what you mean by 'creepy'. Please be descriptive in what the issue is and what you are expecting to see.

Comment: I expect it to do something more useful than starting to float away.

Comment: Generally creepy movements are caused by the Ik target parented or constrained by a bone of the IK chain, so there is a loop: the Ik target moves the chain, which moves the target ..... An IK target should be parented to the root bone, or hips, or any bone which isn't part of the IK chain.

Comment: What should I start to remove to kill the loop

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your bones kind of go off and do their own thing, 9/10 times it is because there is a cyclical dependency somewhere in your armature hierarchy.  The easiest way to diagnose this is to turn on the system console (Windows only, as far as I can tell).

[image: Window -> toggle system console]

From there, it will usually just tell you.

[image: Console showing offending bone hierarchy]

Fixing it is a matter of reorganizing your bone dependencies to not be self-referential.  What that means precisely depends on the model, but remember that an IK control bone cannot be parented to a bone it controls (i.e. a IK control foot cannot be parented to the shin it controls through IK).

Answer (score 0):

The bone you're moving is parented to the bone that is controls. Just parent the bone that you are moving manually to the bone that is the parent of the last moving bone in your IK chain.